# memcached calling wrong libevent

Tags: linux, centos, memcached

When I try to run memcached from shell I get:

memcached: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-1.1a.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

However, i've installed a newer version using yum install libevent. I have also created a .conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ to say where it is. I have confirmed that libconfig is loading it from the correct location.

so, how do I get memcached to load it from the correct place?

I've done yum install memcached and that has installed memcached 1.4.5-1.e15 and libevent 1.4.13-1. Running Centos5.2 final. I've gone for even removing both and trying again, still no go.

Comment: Your system is more than three years out of date. Update it. `yum --obsoletes update`

Comment: @MichaelHampton Might that mess up a few things (configs/etc)?

Comment: Not updating is _much worse_.

Comment: hm, not so sure that is true. This is on a development environment for a small team. We don't have the resources to be fixing numerous config files just becuase we should 'update' something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> memcached: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-1.1a.so.1:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

```
yum provides */libevent-1.1a.so.1
...
compat-libevent-11a-3.2.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64 : Abstract asynchronous event notification library - backwards compatibility
Repo        : rpmforge
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libevent-1.1a.so.1
```

> so, how do I get memcached to load it from the correct place?

Install `compat-libevent-11a` and try again.